# Nested simple_form with polymorphic association. Unpermited parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

It's a lot of question about it all around, but I can't find the answer.
I've:

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :descriptions, :as => :describable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :descriptions
end
```

**description.rb**

```
class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :describable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**groups_controller.rb**

```
   def update
        @group = Group.find(params[:id])
        if @group.update_attributes(group_params)
          flash[:success] = "yes"
          redirect_to groups_path
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
   end


   private

      def group_params
        params.require(:group).permit(:owner_id, :domain, descriptions_attributes: [:id, :content])
 end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @group do |f| %>
    <% if @group[:domain].blank? %>
        <%= f.input :domain %>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.input :domain, readonly: true %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :owner_id, readonly: true %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :descriptions do |description| %>
        <%= description.input :content %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

In console I've `Unpermitted parameter: description` and nested attribute does not created. What should I do to save it at last?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Rails does not convert form `name` to `names_attributes` when generating form for nested polymorphic connection, this:

```
... description: [:content, :other_param, ...]
```

Works fine for me for polymorphic child.