# Private fields for multiple models, how to make on RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, relationship, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have 4 models with complex relations. 3 of them should have descriptions, that should be enable only for user who's create. In other words every user has his own description for Group (for example), or for Post, o something else. Let's talk about only one model, because others are very same. What I have:
**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:vkontakte]
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :descriptions
end
```

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :descriptions, :as => :describable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :descriptions
end
```

**description.rb**

```
class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :describable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

table for descriptions

```
create_table "descriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id" -- belongs_to
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "describable_id"
    t.string   "describable_type"
  end
```

How to display the description for group that belongs to current_user (I use devise)? How to build an update form with nested description?

I try to do it, but it's not work. I've ask question about part of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231414/nested-simple-form-with-polymorphic-association-unpermited-parameter).

Comment: You're missing part of the polymorphic association in the User model, it should be `has_many :descriptions, as: :describable` (you have it correctly in the Group model)

Comment: @Roma149 User is not describable model. It's just has many descriptions with has_many - belongs_to. And this descriptions describes models group, post, etc.

Comment: Ok, but there's no `belongs_to :user` in the `Description` model, so I guess you'd get an error if you tried to use that association.

Comment: @Roma149 thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have an extra model called `description`?

Although it's not a problem in itself, you really *don't* need to have a model just for description.

--

**Profile**

Instead, you may wish to put the details into a *profile* model, or simply in the *user* model (there's nothing wrong with [adding extra attributes to a Devise mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20760338/1143732)l).

We use a *profile* model, which gives us the ability to add as many "extra" fields as we want to the `user` model:

[image]

You can set it up like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
   before_create :build_profile

   delegate :description, :name, to: :profile, prefix: false #-> @user.description
end

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will allow you to create a single profile per user, have that profile built when the user is created, and then change as many options inside the profile as you wish.

Comment: @Rich_Peck My English is not so good, sorry. I've update my question with some more explanations. So any user can make description for group, board, post, etc. It will be something like a private note for record of any of types. And I need that to be visible only for its creator/owner. And you answer to me how to add description to User object, if I correctly understand you.

Comment: Yes I answered what I thought you were asking. If a user can create a description for a group/board etc, then it will be a totally different answer. I will update in a minute